# Jelly bean phone won't let me get to the APN setting

Tags: apn

I just bought a android Jelly Bean phone and I use straight talk, I still have a active Sim card, but the phone won't let me get to set the Apn. When I press on settings for the Apn I doesn't go there. Is there another way to get there to set the APN? Please help. Thank you

Comment: Do you get to the list of APNs? Maybe a screenshot indicating what you are trying might help.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it was a little misleading / not-leading to anywhere. With the following steps `Jelly Bean` (v4.1.2) let me go set a new `APN` with `Samsung Galaxy S 4G Relay`:

1. `Settings` --> may need to press `More settings` --> `Mobile Networks` --> `Access Point Names`
2. Press the "button that leads to setting page" (sorry I don't know how to call this button. On my device it's one of the three main hardware buttons where the others are "Back", "Home"). There you'll see `New APN` and `Reset Default`.